# Reactive core webclient api

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

> webClient.post().uri(url)
> .headers(this::setHeaders)
> .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request))
> .retrieve()
> .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::isError, this::logthiserrorresponse)
> .bodyToMono(clazz)
> .doOnError(error -> {
> throw new SomeException(error.getMessage());
> })
> .block();